# Rest types may only be created from object types. ts(2700)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom input component for my project similar to how I have created the custom button component as well:

### Button Component (this works)

```js
export type ButtonProps = {
    color: 'default' | 'primary' | 'red' | 'dark';
    size: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
    fullWidth?: boolean;
} & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ children, color, size, fullWidth, ...buttonProps }) => {
    return (
        <button {...buttonProps}>
            {children}
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

### Input Component (I get the error here)

```js
export type InputProps = {
    color: 'default' | 'primary' | 'red' | 'dark';
    size: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
    fullWidth?: boolean;
} & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const Input: FC<InputProps> = ({ color, size, fullWidth, ...inputProps }) => {
    return (
        <input {...inputProps} />
    );
};

export default Input;
```

I am however getting a Typescript error on `...inputProps`:

> Rest types may only be created from object types. ts(2700)

I'm not really sure what this means and how to fix it.

### EDIT

I do not get the error on the button component, that works perfectly. The input component however throws that error and I can't get past it.

Comment: What is the type that TS is inferring? To check, if you're using VSCode, hover over `inputProps` and it will show the type TS is inferring.

Comment: @AmitJoki I get `(parameter) inputProps: any`

Comment: Do `<input {...(inputProps as Record<string, any>)} />` and see if it works

Comment: @AmitJoki It didn't work, the error actually shows on the arrow function arguments destructuring: `{ color, size, fullWidth, ...inputProps }`.

Comment: @AmitJoki When I hover over `InputProps`, I get `type InputProps = never` instead of the custom type that I defined.

Comment: Yeah that's wrong, `InputProps` should be showing an object/interface like type. If possible, see if you can reproduce this in JSFiddle/Codesandbox and such sites and paste the link here.

Comment: @AmitJoki Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-tuwf70?file=/src/components/Input.tsx) that shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is you're having two props `color` and `size` of exclusive type definitions.

Your `color` and `size` and `InputHTMLAttributes` own `color` and `size` do not overlap at all. They are mutually exclusive.

So when you try to combine both, Typescript infers that to be `never` because it has conflicting types for `color` and `size`.

You can make it work by omitting the color and size type definitions from `InputHTMLAttributes` like below

```
export type InputProps = {
  color: "default" | "primary" | "red" | "dark";
  size: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg";
  fullWidth?: boolean;
} & Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'color' | 'size'>;
```

or by using custom non-clashing names like so

```
export type InputProps = {
  customColor: "default" | "primary" | "red" | "dark";
  customSize: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "lg";
  fullWidth?: boolean;
} & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
```

Comment: Aaaah, amazing! I wouldn't have figured this out myself. I was under the assumption that it would just override the existing one. FYI, I think it's only the `size` that's the issue - leaving `color` as is worked just fine. Thank you!